# How to import AndroidJUnit4

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit

I don't understand how to import AndroidJUnit4.

Always I get an error: Can't resolve symobol AndroidJUnit4.

gradle сonfig:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'


    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
}
```

Also, in SDK manager I have downloaded "Local Maven repository for Suppor Librarues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to mark tests as Android Instrumentation tests and not as standard Unit Tests.

Comment: I have this same problem. What did you mean by marking tests as Android Instrumentation?

Comment: @scoleman2272 , too late, but https://pp.vk.me/c626719/v626719718/2f670/NRRxzxNiEIU.jpg

Comment: What about when using Maven?

Comment: For Maven:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>runner</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>rules</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>

Comment: And:     <instrumentation android:name="android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="com.example.app"/> in AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: @JohnyTex thanks, but I thought that gradle is a standart for android apps

Answer (score 2):

This is done by adding the test to the

- /app/src/androidTest   Directory instead of the
- /app/src/test          Directory which is for unit tests only

Or, when you create the test class, add the test by selecting new class when in "Android Instrumentation Tests" tab of the Project tree

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use `AndroidJUnit4` in unit testing, add the following dependency into your app's build.gradle file:

```
testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:<version>"
```

Latest versions can be found in it's [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.ext/junit).